# Can I have Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL run together?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I'd like to know if it's possible to have both Linq-to-SQL and Entity Framework running side-by-side. Our current configuration is Linq-to-SQL and we'd like to eventually move to EF. But there's just too much going on in the Linq-to-SQL side right now and we'd like to do it in phases.

so any chance we can just start writing new stuff in entity framework but leave the older stuff running as is? And is it worth it?

Comment: +1 But may I ask why you're moving to EF?  What is it that L2S is not providing?

Comment: I've had the opportunity to work with an ORM before - alot cleaner code, no ugly joins, no sql, and the program evolves much, much faster. ORMs are the future imho. Ruby has Active Record. Apple has coredata. Now Microsoft has Entity Framework. It's about time!

Comment: I may be wrong here but L2S *`IS`* an ORM

Comment: Not really. The relationships are still done via linq (aka embedded sql). In EF there's no need for any of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using the two technologies in the same project, but you can't share the contexts or the models between the two.

Assuming you are willing to pay the price for the differences, there is nothing to stop you from using both in your project.

Comment: Yeah that's not going to be a problem @Shitzel.